# Change background color/image of TTThumbsViewController

Tags: iphone, three20

can I change the background image of my TTThumbsViewController. It's the thumbnail overview screen and at the moment it is white. Can I turn it to transparent?

Thx :-)

Answer (score 5):

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
  }

Comment: Nice one Michael, was scratching my head, missed the "tableView" - was trying on the "View" - Probably did'nt look at the class reference properly :) - Thanks again, up vote!